# New ways of connecting levels of multi-story modular buildings

Tags: design, moc, modular-buildings

Compare these two instructions from the Green Grocers and Pet Shop modular building and you may notice (other than the background colour) that the top of the walls of the buildings are both arranged differently:

[image]

Tiles are raised at certain lengths of the wall to ensure the floor above will stay in place.

[image]

The floor above is secure using the relatively new [92593 modified plate](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92593). The new plates occasionally 'lock' into the floor above when it's removed, leaving an impression of where the plate once was. However few pieces are required.

I'm building a multi-story police station with a large area (32X62) and I'm looking for a suitable way of connecting floors with as few bricks as possible.

Comment: The "without tiles" part seems difficult, and puzzles me a bit - why not?

Comment: @Joubarc: I don't have enough tiles in the right colour, I can probably get rid of that as it might be too much to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ideas I can think of, which are not using "tiles" as such, but similarly flat surfaces:

- Technic beams - holes attached to studs of the lower part of the building, and in some holes (which have to be above tiles), pegs/axles for the upper part to fit into.
- 1x1 "cheese" slopes - and inverted on the upper part (or use regular inverted 33° slopes), which makes the upper part fit in the lower as if in a funnel. (Not very different from using tiles)

Comment: I've considered the first option briefly before but the second idea sounds more interesting. I have many spare cheese slopes I can use but I would probably have to use tiles for the majority of the wall.